# Jquery on("click", function event

Tags: jquery, onclick

I currently have a very simple jquery function where if the menu is pushed then the menu is shown.

```
$(".menu").on("click", function( event ){
   $(".menulist").css("display","block");
   alert(event);
})
```

i would like to display none again if the menu button is clicked again or if they click off the menu.

i have tried the off function as follows but then realised it wouldn't work anyway:

```
$(".menu").off("click", function(){
   $(".menulist").css("display","none");     
})
```

any advise as to how to do this? if it helps this will be for a mobile website aswell

EDIT: the event is in the first function as i thought i might be able to use this event to tell if the item was already showing. either that or another though is would i be better on("click" function() to check if the css value of display for the .menu is equal to block or none and then alter the css from there? this would solve the click onto the menu button but not off the menu

Comment: Try using `.hide()` and `.show()` instead of manipulating css yourself.

Comment: jquery .toggle() method shows the element if it is hidden and hides it if it is visible. You could also use something like toggleClass("class") that does the same but adds or removes a class.

Comment: Firstly thank you for everyone's input, the suggestions work but don't work if clicking off the menu (obviously). Any suggestions as to how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$(".menu").on("click", function(){ $('.menulist').toggle() });` to toggle the visibility of the menu list.

**Update**

To close the menu when you click `off` the menu element, just catch the click event on the body tag and close the menu if it is open:

The entire snippet would look something like this:

```
$('.menu').on('click', function(){ 
    $('.menulist').toggle();
});

$('body').on('click', function(e){
    if(!$(e.target).hasClass('.menu') && $('.menulist').is(':visible')) {
        $('.menulist').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: any idea how to do this if they click off the menu then use .css("display","none");

Comment: not what i used but you got the closest to what i needed so thank you for that.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(".menu").on("click", function( event ){
   $(".menulist").toggle();
})
```

Comment: This works however it doesn't work if you click off the menu. any ideas?

Comment: Of coures it doesn't work when you are not clicking `.menu` (it's only assigned there). If it should work on other places, you can add the click handler to the elelments as well.

Comment: Looking at your comments, do you want something like http://inspiretrends.com/drop-down-menu-tutorials/? With mouse over/out effects?

Comment: its okay i got the answer i needed by using your answer and using the event.stopPropagation(); along with toggle

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [`toggle`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method of jQuery:

```
$(".menu").on("click", function() {
    $(".menulist").toggle();
});
```

Comment: Note this form of `toggle()` has been removed from jQuery since version 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".menu").on("click", function( event ){
   if($(".menulist:visible"))
   {
     $(".menulist").css("display","none");
    }else{
     $(".menulist").css("display","block");
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is as Simply

```
$(".menu").on("click", function( event ){
   $(".menulist").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".menu").on("click", function(){
    var $menulist = $(".menulist");
    $menulist.toggle($menuList.is(":visible"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As `toggle()` function is deprecated:

```
$(".menu").on("click", function( event ){
   if( $(".menulist").css("display")!="none")
    {
       $(".menulist").css("display","none");
    }
    else{
      $(".menulist").css("display","block");
   }
});
```